# Best way to send photo inside mail Django

Tags: html, css, django, email, django-rest-framework

What is the best way to attach my website logo inside activation mail? I tried to do something like this:

```
@lru_cache()
def logo_data():
    with open('templates/authentication/logo.png', 'rb') as f:
        logo_data = f.read()
    logo = MIMEImage(logo_data)
    logo.add_header('Content-ID', '<logo>')
    return logo
```

and then:

```
email=EmailMessage(subject=email_subject, body=email_body, from_email=settings.EMAIL_FROM_USER, to=[user.email])
email.attach(logo_data())
email.content_subtype='html'
email.send()
```

In my html file it looks like this:

```
<img src="cid:logo" style="width: 242px; height: 88px;"/>
```

but it doesn't work. The photo is actually added to the mail in attachments, but the `<img>` tag is empty and looks just like this:
[image]

What is wrong? I read also that attaching photos to email is not recommended because mail gets cause of that extra spam points. What is the best way to do this? Can I send my png logo without attaching it into attachments?

**EDIT**

I tried to add url (to my photo on google drive) like this `<img scr="url">` but these properties disappear inside mail

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CDN, like S3 or Google Cloud bucket to upload the image and add the `url` of the image in your `<img src="URL">` tag.

Comment: I tried to add the url like this ```<img scr="url">``` or ```<img url="url">``` but these properties disappear inside mail

Comment: The image `src`, that you provide must be a public URL, that can be accessed via the internet.

Comment: I set the option on Google Drive: anyone who has the link can view so it is public.

Comment: Maybe gmail doesn't allow ```scr``` in ```img```?

Comment: its src, not scr, if you didnt just typo in the comments here.